# react custom hook return null value and useEffect seems not called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a customer hook used to get the X, Y coordinate from SVG viewbox.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useMouseSVGLocation(
  { clientX, clientY },
  [left, top],
  [canvas_height]
) {
  const [svgX, setSvgX] = useState(null);
  const [svgY, setSvgY] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSvgX(clientX - left);
    setSvgY(canvas_height - (clientY - top));
    console.log(`${clientX - left}`);
  });
  return [svgX, svgY];
}
```

It receives the mouse event position clientX and clientY, it also gets the getBoundingClientRect distance to left and to top. The origin is in the right bottom so the canvas_height is also introduced into the caculation.

```
import useMouseSVGLocation from "../useMouseSVGLocation";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import toJson from "enzyme-to-json";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

function TestComponent() {
  const [svgX, svgY] = useMouseSVGLocation(
    { clientX: 100, clientY: 50 },
    [100, 200],
    [200]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {svgX}, {svgY}
    </div>
  );
}

describe("test useMouseSVGLocation custom hook", () => {
  it("test it in a function component", () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent></TestComponent>);
    wrapper.update();
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(wrapper.find("div").text()).toEqual("0, 350");
  });
});
```

The above is my unit test, I expect it will pass but actually it didn't.

The result is

> ● test useMouseSVGLocation custom hook › test it in a function
> component
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: "0, 350"
> Received: ", "
> ```

Also from the snapshot, it's

> // Jest Snapshot v1, ...
>
> exports[`test useMouseSVGLocation custom hook test it in a function component 1`] = `<div>   ,  </div>`;

Answer (score 0):

Seems like useEffect does not work on mount when used inside custom hook. You can just set starting values in useState and add dependency array to useEffect if you want to update values.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useMouseSVGLocation(
  { clientX, clientY },
  [left, top],
  [canvas_height]
) {
  const [svgX, setSvgX] = useState(clientX - left);
  const [svgY, setSvgY] = useState(canvas_height - (clientY - top));

  useEffect(() => {
    setSvgX(clientX - left);
    setSvgY(canvas_height - (clientY - top));
    console.log(`${clientX - left}`);
  }, []); // deps

  return [svgX, svgY];
}
```

Comment: The error is gone, but useEffect seems still not called @vairaden

Comment: I felt it might be due to the useMouseSVGlocation is not mounted when TestComponent return a value, hence the Receieved value is always ', '

Comment: if I use `let wrapper = mount(<TestComponent></TestComponent>);` in my unit testing, then useEffect will be called.